# Password typing is not allowed in puppeteer ruby

Tags: ruby, puppeteer

I tried `page.type_text`, `page.keyboard.type_text` and inputting via JavaScript using
`page.evaluate` and nothing seem to work. Is there anything I need to look into the documentation that I am missing right now?

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        12: from dummy_file.rb:85:in `<main>'
        11: from dummy_file.rb:68:in `run'
        10: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puppeteer-ruby-0.32.4/lib/puppeteer/page.rb:868:in `evaluate'
         9: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puppeteer-ruby-0.32.4/lib/puppeteer/frame.rb:59:in `evaluate'
         8: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puppeteer-ruby-0.32.4/lib/puppeteer/dom_world.rb:126:in `evaluate'
         7: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puppeteer-ruby-0.32.4/lib/puppeteer/execution_context.rb:40:in `evaluate'
         6: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puppeteer-ruby-0.32.4/lib/puppeteer/execution_context.rb:206:in `evaluate_internal'
         5: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puppeteer-ruby-0.32.4/lib/puppeteer/execution_context.rb:60:in `evaluate_with'
         4: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puppeteer-ruby-0.32.4/lib/puppeteer/cdp_session.rb:24:in `send_message'
         3: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/puppeteer-ruby-0.32.4/lib/puppeteer/concurrent_ruby_utils.rb:36:in `await'
         2: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1471:in `value!'
         1: from /home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1257:in `wait_until_resolved!'
/home/requisitioner/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1257:in `raise': Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Forbidden action: password typing is not allowed (Puppeteer::Connection::ProtocolError)
```

Comment: Better use WATIR.